# Django admin custom choice formfield choice

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the django admin I'm trying to create a custom choice if a field in the database is None or with a value but I cannot make it work I can only get the whole queryset but I cannot get the id of the data so I can filter the request.

Any suggestions?

```
def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        ordered = False
        qs = self.get_queryset(request)
        for query in qs:
            if query:
                if query.order:
                    ordered = True
        if db_field.name == "status":
            if ordered:
                kwargs['choices'] = (
                    ('Ordered', 'Ordered'),
                    ('Shipped', 'Shipped'),
                    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
                    ('Late', 'Late'),
                    ('Never Arrived', 'Never Arrived'),
                )
            else:
                kwargs['choices'] = (
                    ('Shipped', 'Shipped'),
                    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
                    ('Late', 'Late'),
                    ('Never Arrived', 'Never Arrived'),
                )
        return super(xxxxxx, self).formfield_for_choice_field(
            db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since at the point when this function is called, the model instance has already been retrieved, you could just hook into that retrieval and make the model instance available in the current request context so you can use it easily anywhere you have the request:

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request._admin_obj = super(xxxxxx, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
    return request._admin_obj

def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "status":
        obj = request._admin_obj
        if obj and obj.order:
            kwargs['choices'] =  # ordered_choices
        else:
            kwargs['choices'] =  # unordered_choices
    return super(xxxxxx, self).formfield_for_choice_field(
        db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Another way would be to use a custom `ModelForm` in your admin and override its `__init__` to modify the field's choices based `self.instance`.